# Is it possible to developp an iOS or OS X App in LLVM IR?

Tags: ios, macos

I was wondering what the possibilities are to use clang and LLVM IR as a classical assembler, i.e. if it is possible to create directly a small App in LLVM IR and compile it with clang to make an iOS App or an OS X excutable ?

If this is allowed, would it be possible to create a compiler for a new programming language simply by targeting the LLVM IR ? Or is there some locking by Apple to prevent it ? Then we would need to transform it to Objective-C or Swift to be able to compile it...

Regards,